# Doesn't POST next questions of the subject

Tags: php

```
<?php
$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE subject_id='$subject' AND question_id='$question'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($singleSQL);
$thisQuestion = $row['question'];
$type = $row['type'];
$question_id = $row['question_id'];

$q = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand()");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
    $answer = $row2['answer'];
    $correct = $row2['correct'];

    $answers .= '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'">'.$answer.'</label> 
    <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br /><br />
    ';
}

$output = ''.$q.','.$answers.',<span id="btnSpan"><button onclick="post_answer()">Atsakyti</button></span>';

echo $output;
?>
```

Doesn't POST questions on selected subject. The do not find the question in database, because questions have different subject ID and it's not in any order.

```
var p = new XMLHttpRequest();
var id = document.getElementById('qid').value;
var url = "userAnswers.php";
var vars = "qid=" + id + "&radio=" + x();
p.open("POST", url, true);
p.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
p.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (p.readyState == 4 && p.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '';
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var response = hr.responseText.split("|");
                if (response[0] == "finished") {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response[1];
                }
                var nums = hr.responseText.split(",");
                document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = nums[0];
                document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = nums[1];
                document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML += nums[2];
            }
        }
        hr.open("post", "questions.php", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.send("subject=<?php echo $subject; ?>&question=<?php echo $next; ?>");
    }
}
p.send(vars);

}
```

this is the function that button triggers

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you are asking. Which part isn't working, the first query?

Comment: code works until the button is clicked, then it doesnt find other question

Comment: So basically `<button onclick="post_answer()">` isn't working? That seems like a JavaScript function `post_answer()`, and you need to show the code for that, and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: well in my knowledge, button works, but there is a problem, that code doesnt find the aswer, becouse in datadase every question has its own id and subject_id. The subject_id is the problem that need o be fixed, becouse without it everything worked fine.

Comment: Then pass the ID as an argument of the function when you post it, and deal with it inside the function? Kind of hard to tell without seeing the actual code for the function.

Comment: i tryed that, but it didnt work

Comment: i would like to show full code, but it doest allow me to put it in comments

Comment: Please don't add code to comments, update your question with it instead.

Comment: updeted the question, i hope it would make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

check your query. `$question_id` missing.

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question_id' ORDER BY rand()");
```

Comment: it's not missing :( i just didnt put it :(